# Dificuldade em posicionar tabela na tela com bootstrap - layout apenas

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso fazer um layout em minha página, da seguinte forma. Que eu eu tenha três controles textbox, um em baixo do outro e pegando do outro lado todo o restante com uma table. Veja abaixo como eu preciso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei de várias formas, diminuindo o meu grid de 12 para 6 e o que acontece quando eu coloco a imagem é o seguinte: A imagem realmente fica à direita dos controles, mas empurra os controles para baixo. A tabela que eu fiz é apenas um exemplo.

Veja abaixo como ficou a tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu cshtml. Essa tabela é apenas para testes, os valores não tem nada a ver, apenas estou testando o layout da tela.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CadastroAcesso";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
}

<h2>Cadastro de Acesso ao Sistema</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="txtUsuarioRede">Usuário de Rede:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="txtUsuarioRede" id="txtUsuarioRede" placeholder="Digite um usuáruo da rede">
            </div>
            <table data-url="data1.json" data-height="299" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                        <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                        <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id" class="col-md-2">Item ID</th>
                        <th data-field="name" class="col-md-6">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                            Item Name
                        </th>
                        <th data-field="price" class="col-md-4">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                            Item Price
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id" class="col-md-2">Item ID</th>
                        <th data-field="name" class="col-md-6">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                            Item Name
                        </th>
                        <th data-field="price" class="col-md-4">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                            Item Price
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id" class="col-md-2">Item ID</th>
                        <th data-field="name" class="col-md-6">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                            Item Name
                        </th>
                        <th data-field="price" class="col-md-4">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                            Item Price
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="txtUsuarioRede">Usuário de Rede:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="txtUsuarioRede" id="txtUsuarioRede2" placeholder="Digite um usuáruo da rede">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu colocaria a tabela em uma coluna e as inputs em outra, pra dividir a tela. Não sei se é o que você quer mas ficaria assim:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="txtUsuarioRede">Usuário de Rede:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="txtUsuarioRede" id="txtUsuarioRede" placeholder="Digite um usuáruo da rede">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="txtUsuarioRede">Usuário de Rede:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="txtUsuarioRede" id="txtUsuarioRede2" placeholder="Digite um usuáruo da rede">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table data-url="data1.json" data-height="299" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                    <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                    <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" class="col-md-2">Item ID</th>
                    <th data-field="name" class="col-md-6">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                        Item Name
                    </th>
                    <th data-field="price" class="col-md-4">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                        Item Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" class="col-md-2">Item ID</th>
                    <th data-field="name" class="col-md-6">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                        Item Name
                    </th>
                    <th data-field="price" class="col-md-4">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                        Item Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" class="col-md-2">Item ID</th>
                    <th data-field="name" class="col-md-6">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                        Item Name
                    </th>
                    <th data-field="price" class="col-md-4">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                        Item Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```